# Why does my Honda aviator take more than 15 min to kick start?

Tags: honda, scooter, hero-honda

In the morning, my Honda Aviator scooter takes too much time to kick start and once started then it will start easily the next time in two to three kicks.

The electric starter is not working due to a dead battery.

I consulted with a mechanic and he said that it could be because of the battery problem but I am not convinced that this is the reason.

A second possible reason could be an issue with the valves.

So can anybody tell me what the probable reason may be?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! As with all things mechanical, fix the known issues before you try to fix the unknown things. In this case, it would be your battery. It could very well be the battery is the issue, but you won't know until you remedy the battery issue. You could be chasing a problem which otherwise wouldn't exist, spending a lot of time and money in the process. I'm not sure what you are saying by "valve". Do you mean the carburetor or the actual valves in the engine? If so, it would NOT be the valvetrain at fault here.

Comment: Yes valve in the engine...

Comment: But I don't understand that,  what is the connection of battery and kick start ?

Comment: That's the thing, you won't know if there is a connection until the battery is replaced. Here's an analogy for you: Say, there's no gas in the tank, but you don't know that. The scooter won't start so you go about searching for the problem. You replace the carburetor, yet the scooter still won't start. You've now wasted a lot of time and money, only now realizing there's no fuel. You finally put fuel in and the bike starts. There may be a connection between the battery and why it is hard to start. You know the battery needs changed. It might fix all your issues, but you won't know until you do

Comment: My mechanic has checked that by replacing battery problem got resolved but he insisted me to do valve diagnostics ...

Comment: He said me that this issue is because of the valve problem .... After 5 to 6  months you will again face this issue .... Your battery will get dead because this issue after 5-6 month

Comment: Is this making any sense ?

Comment: It makes absolutely NO sense to me. To my knowledge, one has absolutely NOTHING to do with the other. I think I'd find a new mechanic. If you've already had the battery changed and it seems to be working as you'd expect, I'd ride it until the wheels fall off.

Comment: This issue is not only persist in the morning

Comment: After ride if the scooter is idle for some time  in that case also it refuse to start smoothly

Comment: If replacing the battery worked then it is the very likely culprit | Batteries die when left for a long time without occasional charging. | If the bike starts well after being on charge overnight then the battery is a major likelihood. ||Valve problems arise in mechanics heads when they need to make some money from you - these can be best fixed by leaving the valves alone and instead getting a new mechanic.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your Aviator has an ignition coil, rather than a magneto, to generate the spark. That means that it relies on the battery to have enough charge to generate the spark, so likely the ignition is only producing sparks once you've cranked the engine over enough to put a little charge into the battery.

Engines with magnetos that generate the spark directly from the rotation of the crank - there's a magnet in the magneto rotor that excites the ignition coil separately from the generator coils that power the charging and lights - can start even if the battery is completely flat, but yours will not.

Conclusion - it's likely that you battery is not holding any charge after running, so you will need to replace  it.

Comment: I think you are saying to replace the battery, it may make sense to call that out directly.

Answer (score 1):

First, replace the battery if you know it's bad. If the engine won't start when "cold," the choke on the carburetor is possibly the problem.  Any gasoline engine requires a small amount of fuel enrichment upon starting when the engine is "cold."  This is accomplished by the choke mechanism, which partially closes off airflow to the carb with a flap.  Reduced airflow means more fuel to air ratio during the times the engine needs fuel enrichment. The flap movement is spring loaded and controlled manually, electronically or by engine temperature.  If the choke flap fails to close when the engine is cold, the engine will be extremely hard to start. 
Keep in mind that the engine may start just fine once the engine is warm, when the additional fuel flow is not needed.
Another factor might arise if the engine hasn't been used for some time.  Today's gasoline is more volatile and less stable for long term.  As the gasoline evaporates, it sometimes leaves solid deposits inside the carb that can clog fuel passageways.  If the passageways are blocked, even partially, you won't get full fuel flow and the engine will be harder to start.
Summation:  Replace the battery if you know it's bad, regardless.
Use good quality fuel and make sure the carb internals and choke are clean and working properly.  I'd also suggest looking here:
http://www.vicky.in/faqs/honda-aviator/what-is-the-solution-for-starting-problem-in-honda-aviator/

Comment: Yes this scooter was idle for atlest 1 year

Comment: I serviced this replace chock wire recharged battery and started using it ..... After  10 to 15 days I started observing this issue .....

Answer (score 1):

If replacing the battery worked then it is the very likely culprit.

Batteries die when left for a long time without occasional charging.
If the bike starts well after being on charge overnight then the battery is a major likelihood.

Valve problems arise in mechanics heads when they need to make some money from you.
This type of problem can be best fixed by leaving the valves alone and instead getting a new mechanic.